# Yii: code for displaying all information from database

Tags: php, yii

I am really new to YII framework so bear with me guys. =)
here's my code.

```
    public function actionList()
{
$Employee = new employee;

$data = array('employee' => $Employee);
$this->render('Employee_Display', $data);
}



        <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($employee as $row): ?>
        <td><?php $row['employee_firstname']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get the list of employees names and display it on a tabular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public function actionList()
    {
      $Employee = employee::model()->findAll();
      $data = array('employee' => $Employee);
      $this->render('Employee_Display', $data);
    }
        <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($employee as $row): ?>
        <td><?php $row->employee_firstname; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I have error sir since it's an instance I think this should do it $result = $Employee->findall();